# Is this way of using the method GET wrong?

Tags: php, html, sql, get

There is something I've been working and I ran into a problem that I could only solve doing this

```
header("Location:messages.php?ID_Conversation=$row[ID]");
```

Is this "wrong"?

Comment: Why should it be wrong?

Comment: missing the full URL is 'wrong'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not wrong exactly.  You are redirecting to a resource and passing information to that resource as part of the URL, and this is perfectly acceptable.

However, the part that is wrong is the way the URL is structured.  If you are going to be doing this with any regularity, you will want to get into the habit of setting the location as precisely as possible.

At the very least this is to say that you should set the full path relative to the domain root:

```
header("Location:/any_directories/messages.php?ID_Conversation=$row[ID]");
```

And at the best, this means including the domain and protocol as well:

```
header("Location:https://yourdomain.com/any_directories/messages.php?ID_Conversation=$row[ID]");
```

To simplify this, create a helper function or object to handle this kind of redirect.

```
function redirect($url) {
    header("Location:https://yourdomain.com/$url");
}

redirect("any_directories/messages.php?ID_Conversation=$row[ID]");
```

Obviously there are other considerations in the above function, passing data for the GET query as an array maybe, discovering the domain and/or protocol, etc, and it should not be used as it is written, but the idea is sound.